# Printing the history using cookies in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Cookies </title>
    </head>
    <body>
<h1> Cookies Concept </h1>
        <form method="get" action="index.php">
           Enter Your Name:  <input type="text" name="name">
            <input type="submit" name="done"> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['name']))    
{
    if(empty($_COOKIE['name']))
    {
        setcookie('name',$_GET['name']."<br",time()+86400);
    }
   else 
    {
        setcookie('name',$_GET['name'].<br>".$_COOKIE['name'],time()+86400);    
    }    
}    
if(isset($_COOKIE['name']))
{
        echo $_COOKIE['name'];
}
else 
{
    echo "Cookie cannot be set";
}
?>
```

I want to print the last ten name entered . How to do this I don't know please help me ?

Comment: You can't. Not unless you store them somewhere else as well. Cookies are stored on the user's computer, not on the server. There's no way you have concurrent access to the last 10 cookies, or if you do (ie, if there are more than 10 concurrent users, it will be a real hassle to pull all of their cookies, concoct it, and display it on one site (you will have to pull the cookies for all users on all pages and filter out the last 10). Forget about it, find another way to do what you want.

Comment: Exactly what @junkfoodjunkie said. Plus I want to add that anyone can easily manipulate cookies set by the `$_COOKIE` function. So if you really want to use `$_COOKIE` and not sessions, make sure you also set the allowed path, domain and HttpOnly-parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the last 10 from the same user you can use serialize to save an array in the cookie. But remember that will not share info between users since cookie is just for that visitor.
For example:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){ #get the name   
  $name = strip_tags($_GET['name']);
  $names = []; # just names in case there is no names array
  if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie'])){ #read cookie    
    $names = unserialize($_COOKIE['names']);    
  }   

  array_unshift($names, $name); #put the name in begging of the list 

  if(count($names) > 10 ){ #remove last entry if have more then 10   
    array_pop($names);    
  }  
  setcookie('names', serialize($names), time()+3600);
}

//to print just read cookie and  
foreach($names as $name ){   
  echo $name;   
}
```